# JavaScript Array filter dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ecmascript-6

I want to filter array based on drop down selection. How can I do it

My dropdown

```
<select class="custom-select" name="" id="Seats">
            <option selected value="">Any</option>
            <option value="le 5"><= 5</option>
            <option value="le 10"><= 10</option>
            <option value="le 15"><= 15</option> 
            <option value="le 20"><= 20</option>
            <option value="le 25"><= 25</option>
            <option value="le 30"><= 30</option> 
            <option value="le 35"><= 35</option> 
            <option value="le 50"><= 50</option> 
            <option value="gt 50">> 50</option>
          </select>
```

And I am filtering something like this (Please note availableRooms is arraylist)

```
availableRooms = availableRooms.filter(d => d.Seats > 50)
```

but I was looking dynamic query

```
availableRooms = availableRooms.filter(d => d.Seats $("#Seats option:selected").text().trim())
```

last line gives me error, how can we do that

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: what is availableRooms?

Comment: just syntax error

Comment: @Roy.B it is arraylist

Comment: try - `(d => d.Seats>parseInt($("#Seats option:selected").text().trim(),10))` - syntax error because of missed `>`and you would need integer conversion

Comment: @NithinKumarBiliya It will not work in all case as you see options

Comment: Doubt you want to override the variable `availableRooms` and lose the rest of the original array. What if user makes another change? Also what does array look like...no sample was provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the selectedOption based on `' '` and then check if first part is `'le'` or `'ge'`. Based on it make the appropriate comparison.

You can use [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). The **split()** method splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings, using a specified separator string to determine where to make each split.

```
availableRooms = availableRooms.filter(d => {
  var selectedOption=$("#Seats option:selected").text().trim().split(' ');
  if(selectedOption[0]==='le') {
    return d.Seats <= parseInt(selectedOption[1],10);
  } else if(selectedOption[0]==='ge') {
    return d.Seats > parseInt(selectedOption[1],10);    
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to detect the `le` and `gt` prefixes and handle them specifically (unless you want to get into using `eval`, which you should avoid where you can — and you can here). For instance:

```
$("#Seats").on("change", function() {
    let [op, value] = $(this).val().split(" ");
    value = +value; // Make it a number
    let filtered;
    if (op == "le") {
        filtered = availableRooms.filter(d => d.Seats <= value);
    } else { // Assume "gt"
        filtered = availableRooms.filter(d => d.Seats > value);
    }
    console.log(filtered);
});
```

Live Example:

```js
const availableRooms = [
  {Seats: 51},
  {Seats: 50},
  {Seats: 49},
  {Seats: 34},
  {Seats: 29}
];

$("#Seats").on("change", function() {
    let [op, value] = $(this).val().split(" ");
    value = +value; // Make it a number
    let filtered;
    if (op == "le") {
        filtered = availableRooms.filter(d => d.Seats <= value);
    } else { // Assume "gt"
        filtered = availableRooms.filter(d => d.Seats > value);
    }
    console.log(filtered);
});
```

```html
<select class="custom-select" name="" id="Seats">
    <option selected value="">Any</option>
    <option value="le 5"><= 5</option>
    <option value="le 10"><= 10</option>
    <option value="le 15"><= 15</option> 
    <option value="le 20"><= 20</option>
    <option value="le 25"><= 25</option>
    <option value="le 30"><= 30</option> 
    <option value="le 35"><= 35</option> 
    <option value="le 50"><= 50</option> 
    <option value="gt 50">> 50</option>
</select>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advise to approach this challenge with Vanilla JavaScript(that is without jQuery). You can grab the `<select>` element like so:

```
var dropdownEl = document.getElementById("Seats");
```

And then access the selected option like so:

```
var dropdownValue = dropdownEl.options[dropdownEl.selectedIndex].value;
```

And then filter like you desired(assuming the rule to filter is what you wrote above `d.Seats > dropdownValue.trim()`):

```
availableRooms = availableRooms.filter(d => d.Seats > dropdownValue.trim());
```

**Another Important Note**
If you could turn the options values to a single object or array that holds your dropdown options like so:

```
var dropdownOptions: [
 {
   text: "<= 5",
   value: "le5"
 },
 {
   text: "<= 10",
   value: "le10"
 },
 {
   text: "<= 15",
   value: "le15"
 },
 ...
]
```

You could more easily render the `<option>` elements and pass the `text` property for the visible part and then can recap the `value`s easily without having the need to parse the selected value like you did with `.text()` and `.trim()` or any other parsing you might need in the future to do on the raw values - all this can be prevented and you would also end up with a more elegant and readable code.

Comment: There is no `String.prototype.text()`

Comment: I went along with the given example. That was the askers logic. But alright will remove that

Comment: `text()` is a jQuery method, you aren't using jQuery

Comment: That is true, I do not need it because I get the direct value which is a string already.

Answer (score -1):

```
var a = $("#Seats option:selected").val().split(' ');
availableRooms = availableRooms.filter(d => {
  if (a[0] == 'le')
    return d.Seats <= parseInt(a[1])
  else 
    return d.Seats > parseInt(a[1])
});
```

Comment: `filter()` requires a boolean returned

Comment: Still have issues though, overwriting the variable makes no sense and `If` is a typo

Comment: What else is wrong? I appreciate your suggestion. Would like to clear that and delete my answer then.